# Copy & Transpose Data from Data Range Selected by User Through Dialogue Box

Tags: vba, excel

I want to run a macro that open a dialogue box that asks for an array. Once the user has selected an array of cells, the macro then copies those, and transposes them to another sheet, starting at a specific cell selected by the user.

This is what I have put together so far from other codes posted on this website. I have very little experience with VBA, and am just starting to try and save time with analyzing data.

Thank you in advance to anyone who can help.

```
Sub CopyPaste()

Dim Rng As Range
Dim WorkRng As Range
Dim Arr As Variant
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer
On Error Resume Next
xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
Arr = WorkRng.Formula
WorkRng.Formula = Arr

Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("Arr").Cut
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: While this question gets asked several times each week, prompt and focussed responses are usually reserved for the questions that include sample code, sample redated data complete and expected results. Without all three it is very difficult to completely understand what you hope to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

This will allow the *user* to pick both the copy range and destination range at run time:

```
Sub KopyKat()
    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range

    Set r1 = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please select source range", Type:=8)
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Set r2 = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please select destination cell", Type:=8)
    r1.Copy
    r2.PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
End Sub
```